# Socket.io: how to keep server running, despite errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

A short preface: I am currently learning Socket.io, coming from Asyncio in Python. I am making multiclient socket servers. In Asyncio with Python, I am used to making a separate class file for my client. So in the event of any errors, the client's specific class only has the error, and it doesn't affect the rest of the server.

Now, I understand classes are sort of "looked down" upon in Node, so I am unsure how to structure this Socket.io chat program. So far, I have the following code:

```js
server.on("connection", (socket) => {
    clientLog(socket.handshake.address, "Client connected.");

    socket.on("auth", (auth) => {
        if(valid(auth['token']))
        {
            var clientBase = {
                "index" : clientsIndex++,
                "addr"  : socket.handshake.address,
                "token" : auth['token'],
            }
            clients[socket] = clientBase;
            clientLog(clients[socket]['addr'], "Client verified.");
        }
        else
        {
            log(socket.handshake.address, "Client failed verification!");
            socket.disconnect();
        }
    });

    socket.on("message", (message) => {
        handleMessage(socket, message);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        if(socket in clients)
        {
            delete clients[socket];
        }
        console.log("Client Disconnected!");
    });
});
```

There is more at the top of the file, but it is not very significant. Basically, this is the start of my simple chat messenger program. Now, there is an issue: when errors come up, the entire program dies. This is different from Python/Asyncio, because in Python, when errors show up, unless they are fatal, the program continues to run, and only the client is disconnected. In Socket.io, the entire program seems to die as soon as the smallest error comes up.

Errors are inevitable, and this chat messenger is planned to be used by a significant amount of people. Therefore, I was wondering if I can restructure this program in a way where any unhandled errors are just logged or something, and the program continues to run. I understand I can do this with `unhandledException`, but I also understand `unhandledException` is unethical, and should be used as a last-resort method.

With that, I was wondering if my program has some fundamental problem in its structure. If so, how should I restructure this program to better handle multiple clients? This is just the base of it, and I can restructure if necessary.

It is just a simple Socket.io program, which passes around messages (and will eventually use MySQL to authenticate users).

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your issue is directly related to Node.js or Socket.io. I'd say you should start using exception handling with try..catch blocks (optionally with finally statement if necessary). This is a generic technique present in every modern programming language.

See: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/errors/what-is-try-catch/

An alternative to try/catch suggested by the same page above:

> But wait, isn't it Node.js convention to not use try-catch?
>
> In the core Node.js libraries, the only place that one really needs to use a try-catch is around JSON.parse(). All of the other methods use either the standard Error object through the first parameter of the callback or emit an error event. Because of this, it is generally considered standard to return errors through the callback rather than to use the throw statement.

According to this alternative technique you should start your callbacks with:

```
if (error){
  //error handling code goes here
}
```

Which is often seen in Node.js codes.
I found a good example here:
https://stackify.com/node-js-error-handling/ at the Handling async (callback) errors section.

```
var request = require('request'); //http wrapped module
function requestWrapper(url, callback) {
    request.get(url, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null, response);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. So would I put that if-statement in each of my socket.on blocks?

Comment: @EarthQuake: simply put yes. See my edit for example and check out the link. That seems to cover quite a lot for node.js error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Can u check on nodemon? Its a package which is used in dev environments to keep the server running in case of run time errors. Use it along with pm2 to run the server in the background.